How to Retrieve the Funding Fee for an Open Position via API on HMX?
I am currently working on integrating HMX into my accounting system and need to fetch the funding fee for an open position via API. Despite going through the documentation, I couldn't find a clear explanation or example of how to accomplish this.
Could someone guide me on which function or endpoint should be used to get the funding fee for an open position on HMX?
Thank you in advance!
